# How to create radiobutton horizontal list via API with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've been trying to create an horizontal radiobutton horizontal list, but somehow I don't get the same visual result as when done with the data-* attributes.

If I do it with code I get squared buttons, while using the attributes I get a nice rounded corner toolbar.

Here is the code I use for creating the button list:

```
$(element).controlgroup({ mini: true, type: "horizontal" });
```

which should be the same as the one I use with the data-* attributes:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
```

I've posted a jsfiddle to show the result

http://jsfiddle.net/simonech/zeDt4/3/

Can someone shad some light on this strange behavior?
Thx
Simone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make them look the same, try this:

```
$("#mycontrolbox").controlgroup({ mini: true, type: "horizontal"});
$("#mycontrolbox").attr("data-role", "controlgroup");
```

updated jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zeDt4/4/

Now, why is this.

I think that jQuery mobile is actually not build upon jQuery UI even though it is currently very close. jQuery mobile is using those data-** attributes to select what is going to be a role of each tag. When the element is added to the html, jqm reads the content and based on what is in these data-role attributes, it decorates / replaces / the current content with its own. This is more about what is done to the element in order how it looks.

On the other hand, when you call

```
$("#mycontrolbox").controlgroup();
```

This does create a jQuery component allowing you to use the methods of that component. etc.
This is close to how the component behaves from the script point of view. This **does not**, however, **add data-role** attribute to the element itself.

Comment: Thx, works fine, even if it looks more like a bug to me as by doing this we are just adding the controlgroup data-role attribute again and probably jquerymobile re-processes it.

Comment: I agree, it does look like a bug or something unfinished to me as well.